# How to express "a person who talks really quickly & carelessly" in English?

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions

When I teach English to children and adults, I realize that some speak slowly but carefully and make less mistakes, whereas some speak really quickly, carelessly and make more mistakes.

Can I say "**he speaks so impetuously**"? or are there any other better or more common terms in English?

Comment: Your use of *but* is a little strange. Normally, it's used to express a contrast between things. I would expect to hear *quickly but carefully* and *slowly but carelessly* rather than the juxtaposition that you're actually using. It would be more natural to say *quickly **and** carelessly* and *slowly **and** carefully*.

Comment: @JasonB: I guess he/she means that although slowness might be a downside in speech, care is an advantage to the quality of speech. So there is a contrast there.